# Существует ли способ подключится к Sqlite используя Stream в C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Для подключения к Sqlite используется строка подключения, но меня интересует есть ли возможность подключения к Sqlite файлу используя поток?

Я хочу создать файл, в котором в начале файла будет идти заголовок с дополнительными данными, а после заголовка данные Sqlite.

Мне нужно что-то вроде такого:

```
    Stream stream = null!;
    using SqliteConnection connection = new(stream);
    // CRUD operations.
```

Comment: Sqlite использует несколько файлов (например, журнал пишется в отдельный файл), поэтому я не уверен, что технически возможно обойтись одним стримом

Comment: Какова конечная цель этого?

Comment: Если страдаете хернёй, как обычно делают начинающие, чтобы ВСЁ упаковать в один файл, ну так сделайте дополнительную таблицу в sqlite для хранения ваших дополнительных данных.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я хочу иметь возможность менять способ хранения данных. В заголовке файла будет содержаться тип, в котором данные хранятся. Да и просто интересно есть ли возможность подобного.

Comment: И это изначально плохая идея, потому что вы автоматически ограничиваете себя только теми типами, которые могут работать с дотнетовым Stream (а sqlite скорее всего не может)

Comment: Гм, какой-то странный способ. | Вообще, в sqlite любая колонка может хранить данные любого типа. [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) См. Type Affinity

Comment: Опять-таки, заведите отдельную таблицу для метаданных. / Кстати, метка entity framework зачем? Если ещё и он используется, то о ручном управлении типами следует забыть.

Comment: Заклевали парня. Ответ - нет. Просто используйте отдельный файл для хранения произвольной информации.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я прекрасно знаю, что sqlite хранит данные "динамически" и я прекрасно знаю, что можно создать доп. таблицу, но мой вопрос заключался не в том как СЧИТАТЬ данные из sqlite, а в том КАК ПОДКЛЮЧИТСЯ С ПОМОЩЬЮ ПОТОКА и можно ли вообще так сделать, не стоит думать, что я прям новичок, пару лет в c# я имею (как студент правда) но тем не менее, что-то да понимаю. Ну а на счет того, что "делают начинающие, чтобы ВСЁ упаковать в один файл" видимо разработчики sqlite тоже начинающие раз упаковали все в один файл.

Comment: @andreymal ну sqlite может работать "In-Memory" и чувствует себя нормально (вроде как) и никаких доп. файлов ему для работы не нужно, так что возможность для работы судя по-всему есть.

Comment: @rotabor Печально конечно. Можете опубликовать свой комментарий как ответ на вопрос, чтобы я его пометил как ответ.

Comment: @ryzh86bit In-Memory принципиально другой, потому что не требует обеспечивать целостность и взаимодействие с другими процессами, не смотрите на него

Comment: sqlite использует несколько файлов при необходимости, как уже было сказано в самом первом комментарии. / Не воспринимайте слово "начинающий" как оскорбление в свой адрес. Я, например, тоже начинающий, когда стал пробовать PostgreSQL после нескольких лет работы с Sql Server.

Comment: Реализовать вашу хотелку вполне можно. Открываем документацию: [Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html), [Virtual Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) - разбираемся в формате хранения данных и дописываем драйвер для работы с ними как нам угодно.

Comment: Берём книгу Using SQLite (2010), в ней в частности, описано, как создавать виртуальные таблицы и модули (на чистом Си). И там можно реализовать что угодно! / Но я так и не получил ответа на вопрос: какова конечная цель этого? В чём удобство хранения дополнительных данных в начале файла базы данных?